# HttpClient returns "Cannot read property 'get' of Undefined" [Angular 7]

Tags: angular, class, ecmascript-6, angular-httpclient

I'm trying to create a simple API service in Angular 7 that I can include in any component that needs it. However, whenever I call it from a component, I get an error. For example, if from within my component I call `ApiService.read('/public/flavorsofcandy/')` I get:

`ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined`

Now, I'm unsure why this is, but I feel it's something simple and silly. However, nowhere could I find why this is happening. I feel this is due to me not fully understanding concepts related to classes and whatnot, instead of Angular 7 itself.

*api.service.ts*

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class ApiService {

    private baseUrl = "http://localhost:11000/";
    private http: HttpClient;

    public create = (req:string, options?:any) => {
        this.http.post(this.baseUrl+req, options)
        .subscribe(response=> {return response})
    }

    public read = (req:string, options?:any) => {
        this.http.get(this.baseUrl+req,options)
        .subscribe(response=> {return response})
    }

    public update = (req:string, options?:any) => {
        this.http.put(this.baseUrl+req, options)
        .subscribe(response=> {return response})
    }

    public delete = (req:string, options?:any) => {
        this.http.delete(this.baseUrl+req, options)
        .subscribe(response=> {return response})
    }

};
```

*mycomponent.ts*

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ApiService as api} from '../../scripts/api.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'MyComponent ',
  templateUrl: './MyComponent.html',
  styleUrls: ['./MyComponent.scss'],
})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
  public flavorsList: any;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getFlavors()
  }

  getFlavors() {
    this.flavorsList = api.read('/public/flavorsofcandy/')
  }

}
```

Answer (score 5):

Your `HttpClient` is not defined. In the line of code `private http: HttpClient;` you declare it, but never give it a value so it remains as `undefined`.

The `HttpClient` class is **Injectable**, so we can inject it in a conscructor for your `ApiService` like so:

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}
```

And now we can access it anywhere in this service by calling `this.http.get(someUrl).subscribe(ex => {});`

Comment: This gives me an error `ERROR TypeError: _scripts_api_service__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__.ApiService.read is not a function` but I'll keep playing around to see why.

Comment: @invot Same thing is wrong with `mycomponent.ts`. You need to inject the `ApiService`. The import line should just be `import { ApiService } from '../../scripts/api.service';` and then you would inject it the same way in the constuctor. Ex) `constructor(private api: ApiService) {}` then call it anywhere in that class like `this.api.read(someUrl)`

Answer (score 3):

You're not injecting the `HttpClient`. You need to use the `constructor` to inject it. See https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection. Don't forget to import `HttpClientModule` in your `AppModule`.